# jQuery link conflict when using V2.1.4 jQuery link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datetime

I am using LIMITLESS theme and implementing jQuery link but this link is conflicting. Please help me.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Conflicted by

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information to help you out. Did you remove this link and try ?

Answer (score 0):

That is jQuery too. If it is an older version you can remove second code, or download new one and replace with older in `assets/js/core/libraries` folder while removing first one.
If it is not older there is no need to implement it twice. Also be careful about implementing before every code uses jQuery.